# How to return MySQL rows as columns in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I hope someone can help, I have a database of different odds (betting odds) which are linked to a unique eventID. All of the odds are stored as a row in the MySQL database as per the below description.

```
ID | EventID | BookmakerName | BoommakerURL | BookmakerHome | BookmakerDraw | BookmakerAway

12345 | 111213 | Bookmaker | http://wwww.URL.com | 1.3 | 1.6 | 1.5 <p>
12345 | 111213 | Bookmaker2 | http://wwww.URL2.com | 2.3 | 2.6 | 2.5
```

What i'm looking to do though is to display these in columns as per the below example. I'll be doing a INNER Join on get the team name from another table.

```
EventID | Team | Bookmaker | Bookmaker2 <p>
111213 | HomeTeam | 1.3 | 2.3<p>
111213 | AwayTeam | 1.6 | 2.6<p>
111213 | Draw | 1.5 | 2.5<p>
```

I'm using PHP and managed to loop through the results and display the rows but I'm struggling to change the layout.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm stuck. Happy any MySQL solutions e.g. create a new table or PHP based solutions.

Comment: Easier it you share your code as it is, because otherwise a responder will have to write all the code which will give you few answers.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg If any answers at all, please show us what you have tried, "struggling to change the layout" is an' incredible vague problem description.

Comment: 1. Stop. 2. See normalisation. 3. Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should explain properly what you actually want to do and what you have tried and exactly you have got stuck.
As far as i have understood , this will surely help :

you can join the two tables and can get the data from other table.

For example :

```
Select * from table1
join table2 on table1.EventID=table2.EventID
 where (what ever required condition)
```

Try this it will work for you